# What is the easiest way to install numpy with LAPACK/BLAS?

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-14.04, lapack, blas

I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04.

I would have expected doing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

would've worked but it isn't the case...

The way I tried to check is by doing `locate blas` and found nothing that seemed relevant.

I would like a solution that doesn't involve me compiling from source.

The ideal solution is something that uses the ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 and later, blas and lapack are installed as part of python-scipy and python3-scipy, so you need to install python-scipy. In Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-scipy
```

This command will also install libblas3 (Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms reference implementations, shared library) and liblapack3 (Library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version) as dependencies, and it will also install python-numpy as a dependency if you don't already have it installed.

Comment: For best results with this answer, first uninstall python-numpy package if you installed it using `pip` with the command `sudo pip uninstall python-numpy` .

Comment: See also: [Find out if/which BLAS library is used by Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37190672/562769)

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.show_config()` revealed that I had no BLAS support even though `python3-scipy` was already installed. Uninstalling and re-installing `python3-scipy` and `python3-numpy` fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-scipy python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy python3-numpy
```

Now I have LAPACK/BLAS support:

```
>>> numpy.show_config()
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack']
    language = f77
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = c
blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
    language = c
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack', 'blas', 'blas']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = c
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried to use pip?

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

If you dont have pip install pip with instructions [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/)

Comment: haven't tried pip... generally I'm a bit biased against using pip because to do it properly it seems I have to do virtual environment stuff which doesn't sound that easy. If there is no repository solution pip is probably the next best thing. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I find that `pip` works when having issues. Good at solving at issues

Comment: should I first uninstall numpy I installed through `sudo apt-get`?

Comment: it didn't work, gave me a bunch of errors, couldn't find fortran compilers and a whole bunch of other stuff...

Comment: also, seems to not have tried to download LAPACK /BLAS libaries but expected me to have done it already..

Comment: Try this:

Go to: System -> Synaptic -> Administration -> Package Manager ->
search on lapack (and/or blas), and mark for installation:

libblas3gf
libblas-doc
libblas-dev

liblapack3gf
liblapack-doc
liblapack-dev

-> Apply

Comment: that is for an older version of ubuntu. I think synaptic is no more in 14.04. I'll install that using `apt-get`

Answer (score 1):

I have very good experience with the [anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html) package manager (learning took me 1-2h). In my opinion it is easier to use than venv and more felixble than pip/env alone. After download and setup you have most of the package like numpy ready to go. So no problems like this anymore!