# Find out if/which BLAS library is used by Numpy

Tags: python, c++, macos, numpy, blas

I use numpy and scipy in different environments (MacOS, Ubuntu, RedHat).
Usually I install numpy by using the package manager that is available (e.g., mac ports, apt, yum).

However, if you don't compile Numpy manually, how can you be sure that it uses a BLAS library? Using mac ports, ATLAS is installed as a dependency. However, I am not sure if it is really used. When I perform a simple benchmark, the `numpy.dot()` function requires approx. 2 times the time than a dot product that is computed using the Eigen C++ library. I am not sure if this is a reasonable result.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`numpy.show_config()` doesn't always give reliable information. For example, if I `apt-get install python-numpy` on Ubuntu 14.04, the output of `np.show_config()` looks like this:

```python
blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
...
```

It looks as though numpy is using the standard CBLAS library. However, I know for a fact that numpy is using OpenBLAS, which I installed via the `libopenblas-dev` package.

---

The most definitive way to check on *nix is to use [`ldd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldd_(Unix)) to find out which shared libraries numpy links against at runtime (I don't own a Mac, but I think you can use `otool -L` in place of `ldd`).

- **For versions of numpy older than v1.10:**

  ```
  ~$ ldd /<path_to_site-packages>/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
  ```

  If `_dotblas.so` doesn't exist, this probably means that numpy failed to detect any BLAS libraries when it was originally compiled, in which case it simply doesn't build any of the BLAS-dependent components.
- **For numpy v1.10 and newer:**

  [`_dotblas.so` has been removed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#dropped-support), but you can check the dependencies of `multiarray.so` instead:

  ```
  ~$ ldd /<path_to_site-packages>/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  ```

---

Looking at the version of numpy I installed via `apt-get`:

```
~$ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_dotblas.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff12db8000)
    libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007fce7b028000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fce7ac60000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fce7a958000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fce7a738000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fce7ca40000)
```

`/usr/lib/libblas.so.3` is actually the start of a chain of symlinks. If I follow them to their ultimate target using `readlink -e`, I see that they point to my OpenBLAS shared library:

```
~$ readlink -e /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
/usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it, if `ldd /<path_to_site-packages>/numpy/core/multiarray.so` was higher up in the answer.

Comment: It looks like in numpy 1.16, multiarray was reorganized. I had to run `ldd numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Answer (score 6):

numpy.show_config() just tells that info is not available on my Debian Linux.

However /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/lib has a subdirectory for blas which may tell you what you want. There are a couple of test programs for BLAS in subdirectory tests.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You want to check `numpy.show_config()` to see what libraries are configured.

With the newest `mkl` that should show `libraries = ['mkl_rt']`, before that it should contain several `mkl_` libraries. See also [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-new-linking-model-single-dynamic-library-mkl_rt-since-intel-mkl-103).