# Check numpy installation used libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ubuntu-16.04

I do have numpy as I get no error for

```
import numpy
```

But I want to install Caffe and to decide if I should use Atlas or OpenBLAS I need to know what my numpy is using. I did tried this to know how many numpy I have (I have python 2.7.11 and 2.7.12 for anaconda and python 2.7, 3.5, 3.5m in normal dir)

```
apt-cache policy numpy
```

But it does not show anything.  Moreover, I would like to know whether my numpy is intalled with simple `pip` or optimized with some BLAS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184618/find-out-if-which-blas-library-is-used-by-numpy?

Comment: thank you it does solved 2 of my problems.

Comment: More than the above you can also use `/path/to/pip show numpy` for each of your installations to check which versions you have.

Comment: @DavidW But can you explain why 'apt_cache policy libname' is not working?

Comment: @wrwrwr Are you sure it will work even if I did not installed numpy by pip?

Comment: That's only for the pip installed packages. However, together with `apt-cache` and `conda list numpy` you should be able to find all versions except for those installed manually using `setup.py`. (`apt-cache` will only list distribution packages installed through `apt`, like [`python-numpy`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-numpy)).

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to just pick one Python version, say the default under `python`, and install `numpy` for it (say using `python -m pip install numpy --upgrade`). Otherwise you'll have to find a way to tell Caffe which of your Pythons to use.