# Is there a Numpy or pyTorch function for this code?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, pytorch

Basically is there a Numpy or PyTorch function that does this:

```
vp_sa_s=mdp_data['sa_s'].detach().clone()
dims = vp_sa_s.size()
for i in range(dims[0]):
    for j in range(dims[1]):
        for k in range(dims[2]):
            # to mimic matlab functionality: vp(mdp_data.sa_s)
            try:
                vp_sa_s[i,j,k] = vp[mdp_data['sa_s'][i,j,k]]
            except:
                pass
```

Given that `vp_sa_s` is size `(10,5,5)` and each value is a valid index vp i.e in range 0-9. vp is size `(10,1)` with a bunch of random values.

Matlab do it elegantly and quickly with `vp(mdp_data.sa_s)` which will form a new `(10,5,5)` matrix. If all values in `mdp_data.sa_s` are 1, the result would be a `(10,5,5)` tensor with each value being the 1st value in `vp`.

Does a function or method that exists that can achieve this in less than O(N^3) time as the above code is terribly inefficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with

```py
result = vp[vp_sa_s, 0]
```

note that since your `vp` is of shape `(10, 1)` (it has a trailing singleton dimension) you need to add the `, 0]` index in the assignment to get rid of this extra dimension.

Comment: Man I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much! I was overcomplicating it so much. Would you be able to explain how Numpy interprets that as "fill a result array size == vp_sa_s with values result[I] == vp[vp_sa_s[I]]. As my understanding is that vp[vp_sa_s] would be interpreted as Index VP with the dimensions stored in vp_sa_s?

Comment: @joekadi [Fancy Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in `numpy` is designed specifically to mirror `MATLAB` functionality in this case.

Comment: @joekadi you should not feel bad about your question.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574086/how-is-numpys-fancy-indexing-implemented) is some more information about how it's implemented if you're interested.